# Why was my question closed? A reason stated in the comments could also apply to a prior question of mine that was very productive and helpful

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031669/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-file-to-a-tar-without-writing-it-to-disk-first-in-python) and it got closed. I also posted [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957997/is-there-a-good-way-to-store-large-amounts-of-similar-scraped-html-files-in-pyth) a couple of days prior that I think was very similar. The older of the two got a very helpful answer and the newer a somewhat snarky comment and was closed. I'm told it was closed because it needs to be "more focused", but I don't know how I could make it any more focused.

Both of my questions were about implementing compression in Python and provided no code, but it had a description of ideas that I had thought of so far. I didn't think code would be helpful at all because in both cases my code functioned just fine. I was asking an abstract question about compression and its relevant Python libraries and if there existed any particular function that I was not aware of that could accomplish a task at hand.

Can someone explain what was wrong with the second question that I didn't do in the first? I'd like to better formulate questions going forward, so I don't get snarky comments or closures.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228279/discussion-on-question-by-jaz-why-was-my-question-closed-a-reason-stated-in-the). **If you have an opinion to share, post an answer.**

Answer (score 12):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031669/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-file-to-a-tar-without-writing-it-to-disk-first-in-python) is very close to being an acceptable question. It only needs minor edits to make it ready to receive answers.

However, I do agree with the closure. As posed, it was too abstract; there were not enough details provided in the question itself to constrain the answers. That's a bad thing, and something that our question reviewers watch out for.

I would suggest that you edit the question to add some code showing what you currently have and/or are trying to do. That will give answerers some context and allow them to build on top of what you already have.

As it stands now, your question raises more questions than it does answers. If we see how you're currently doing it, it's easier for us to modify that with a more efficient solution that elides the temporary file.

Once that edit is done, your question can be reopened.

As far as the comment that was left…I don't really think it was snarky, but I don't see the point in rehashing that debate. However, it was not especially *useful*, in that it didn't tell you what you need to fix. (And it contained a misleading implication that "how to" questions might be off-topic and/or that questions that show insufficient "effort" should be closed.) A moderator has deleted it. I've also deleted the other obsolete comments, since the discussion is occurring here.

Aside from that, please don't fall into the trap of using other questions as justification for what is/is not on-topic. Stack Overflow is not a perfect mirror of its own requirements. We get a *lot* of questions, and some do miss getting closed. And, of course, some are incorrectly closed. Instead, evaluate each question in isolation, with respect to [our guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what can be reasonably answered in our format.

Comment: *I don't see the point in rehashing that debate.* Not even with a salted hash? Much tastier.

Comment: Maybe if you serve it up with some corned beef.